# How to render Bounded TaskFlow into Popup

Tags: java, oracle-adf, adf-task-flow

I am working in one project in which ADF technology is being used. So i want to open one Bounded Task flow into Popup. So I made two task flow for this. TaskFlow1 and TaskFlow2.xml. In TaskFlow there is one test.jsff (Please Note this point) page which contain one button. So below is the sample code how i called TaskFlow2.

```
<control-flow-rule id="__27">

    <control-flow-case id="__28">
        <from-outcome>showQues</from-outcome>
        <to-activity-id>initQuestion</to-activity-id>
    </control-flow-case>
    <control-flow-case id="__34">
        <from-outcome>payment</from-outcome>
        <to-activity-id>initPayment</to-activity-id>
    </control-flow-case>
</control-flow-rule>

<control-flow-rule id="__40">
    <from-activity-id>initPayment</from-activity-id>
    <control-flow-case id="__41">
        <from-outcome>showPayment</from-outcome>
        <to-activity-id>taskFlow2</to-activity-id>
    </control-flow-case>
</control-flow-rule>

<method-call id="initPayment">
    <method>#{pageFlowScope.userProfileBB.initPaymentPreferences}</method>
    <outcome>
        <fixed-outcome>showPayment</fixed-outcome>
    </outcome>
</method-call>



<task-flow-call id="taskFlow2">
    <task-flow-reference>
        <document>/WEB-INF/taskflows/TaskFlow2.xml</document>
        <id>test-task-flow-definition</id>
    </task-flow-reference>
        <run-as-dialog>
            <display-type>
                <inline-popup/>
            </display-type>
        </run-as-dialog>

</task-flow-call>
```

This task flow is also set "Run as dialog" and "In line" as well. But not the problem Popup is coming but no task flow rendering. No error in console. 
I noticed one more thing there is no call to TaskFlow2 init method. But when i "changed the "Run as dialog" to "Default". Then everything works fine. 
and it start TaskFlow2 init method.

I read few article but could not find anything on this. Below is link for one article.

```
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/learnmore/39-taskflow-in-popup-169181.pdf
```

Can someone help to find the right cause or give me some other resource to render TaskFlow into popup.

Comment: Did you tried https://blogs.oracle.com/DavidGiammona/entry/task_flow_call_activity_run_as  ?

Comment: @ViswanathLekshmanan I tried this way and follow all the step mentioned in example but its not working

Comment: What u see after that ? Any error?

Comment: Problem is there are not error on console. popup is coming but with one jsf page. No method of Taskflow is being called. But when turnoff the Run as dialog then everything is coming. Data is coming and Taskflow method is also being called.

Answer (score 1):

Check your security settings.
Maybe your task flow doesn't have jazn permissions set.

Comment: Sorry but I really do not know about this permissions. Can you tell me step how can I do this.

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/11gdemos/AdfSecurity/AdfSecurity.html